# C# Question on moving mouse to specific colour

Tags: c#

just a question here. I have written a script in C# to constantly check my screen if a specific colour is on the screen. But this only checks if my mouse is ONLY in the middle of the screen, how can I check on my screen if this colour is anywhere on the screen? And if so, move the mouse to the colour?

My code:

```
private bool SearchPixel(string hexcode)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as Image);
        graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);

        Color desiredPixelColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(hexcode);

            for (int x = 0; x < SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; x < SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height; y++)
                {
                    Color currentPixelColor = bitmap.GetPixel(x, y);


                    if (desiredPixelColor == currentPixelColor)
                    {

                        MessageBox.Show("Found!");
                        return true;
```

Pasted it in here, indents might of messed it up but you still get an idea how I am checking for colour

Comment: where's the script?

Comment: We would need a lot more information to help - firstly showing your "script", but knowing what platform you are using would also be needed.

Comment: This code has several very basic faults - I would recommend running through with the debugger to work out what is wrong (exceptions are thrown, making finding the problems easy). Once fixed - this should find the first position on the screen with your selected colour regardless of where the cursor currently is - you can replace your MessageBox with the following code "Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y);" to move the cursor to that position.